# Typescript - Environment Variable "String" | Undefined Error

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, typeguards

I am passing environment variables from my `lambda-stack` to my lambda function, via the `environment` key and I am receiving an error.

**Passing Variables:**

```
environment: {
  queueArn: sqsStack.sqsQueue.queueArn,
  queueUrl: sqsStack.sqsQueue.queueUrl,
},
```

**Error:**
*Argument of type '{ MessageBody: string; QueueUrl: string | undefined; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SendMessageRequest'.*

**Lambda Code:**

```
  var params = {
    MessageBody: "STRING_VALUE" /* required */,
    QueueUrl: process.env.queueUrl /* required */,
  };

  sqs.sendMessage(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
    else console.log(data); // successful response
  });
```

**Question:**
How do I ensure with typescript that `process.env.queueUrl` is consistently a string with Typescript?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use the [non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#:%7E:text=Non%2Dnull%20assertion%20operator&text=produces%20a%20value%20of%20the,in%20the%20emitted%20JavaScript%20code.). This tells the TypeScript compiler that a value typed as optional cannot be null or undefined.

For this example, if I am 100% sure there will be a value for `process.env.queueUrl`, I can write the following: `process.env.queueUrl!`. This removes the error warning from Typescript.

Answer (score 0):

Try to assign the `typescript interface` type to your object

```js
var params: SendMessageRequest = {
    MessageBody: "STRING_VALUE" /* required */,
    QueueUrl: process.env.queueUrl /* required */,
};
```

I expect `SendMessageRequest` to be something like

```
interface SendMessageRequest { 
    MessageBody: string; 
    QueueUrl: string; 
}
```

Then if your  `process.env.queueUrl` is `undefined` then typescript will tell you, if `process.env.queueUrl` has a type.

If `process.env.queueUrl` has a type, and it's optional, then you might want to wrap the params creation in an if clause, where you test that is it not undefined. This will tell typescript that you don't expect it to be undefined.
eg.

```
if (process.env.queueUrl) {
    var params: SendMessageRequest = {
        MessageBody: "STRING_VALUE" /* required */,
        QueueUrl: process.env.queueUrl /* required */,
    };
}
```